# Google Chrome for AWS Lambda as a layer

Tags: puppeteer, chromium

I'm utilizing the Sparticuz/chromium package along with puppeteer-core for web scraping. Additionally, I've included a layer following the instructions outlined [here](https://github.com/shelfio/chrome-aws-lambda-layer). The code executes successfully when run locally, but upon deployment to AWS, it encounters the following error related to the directory "/var/task/src/functions/bin".

```
import chromium from "@sparticuz/chromium";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import puppeteer from "puppeteer-core";
export const handler = async () => {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      args: chromium.args,
      defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
      executablePath: await chromium.executablePath(),
      headless: chromium.headless as boolean,
      ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    });

    // const page = await browser.newPage();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto("https://shippos.nigerianports.gov.ng/", {
      waitUntil: "domcontentloaded",
      timeout: 120_000,
    });

    const element = await page.waitForSelector("#Apapa2_next");

    const result = await element.evaluate((node) => node.textContent);

    console.log(result);

    console.log("Chromium:", await browser.version());
    console.log("Page Title:", await page.title());

    await page.close();

    await browser.close();

    await page.close();

    await browser.close();
    // await scraperVoceanLineups();
    // await getNigeriaPortsLineups();
    // await getMaputoVesselLineups();
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: `Urls succesfully scraped`,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: `An error occured ${error.message}. Emails were sent to the relevant admins.`,
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: What is the error message and stack trace, please?